# Writing to standard output from c# program

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I have the following C# code

```
class Test 
{
    public static void Main(String[] argv) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Hello "); 
    }
}
```

When I run the program from the command prompt, I do not see output. The c# file name is file.cs and compiles into file.exe.

When I run this from the command prompt:

```
c:\>file.exe
```

I do not see any output. But it works if I run this:

```
c:\>file.exe | more
```

I understand I need to do something other that `console.WriteLine()`. Is there any way that I can redirect all `Console.WriteLine()` calls to standard output?

Comment: well it could be a number of issue's but can't tell without seeing your `Main` section of the code.. please show some relevant code also if you are wanting to pause the console to see the output use Console.Read() or Console.ReadLine() method

Comment: Post some code. And as a side note, don't call it a `DOS shell` or `DOS window`. Those haven't existed since like Windows 98. Its just called a `command window` now.

Comment: If you could see it with `| more` option than *probably*, you have other statements coming to console, causing it to scroll.

Comment: What is your project type? If it's a Windows Forms app, that would explain it.

Comment: class Test
 {public static void Main(String[] argv)
  {

   Console.WriteLine("Hello ");                    }}

Comment: Code in the post please. You can't read it in comments.

Comment: How do you compile the code?

Comment: Are you compiling it as a Console application? Not as a Class Library or Winform application...

Answer (score 3):

Application type was set to Windows application in Visual Studio project properties.
I set the application type to "Console". This fixed the issue. Now all Console.WriteLine statements gets printed to command window.